# Form information in a table cant be submitted after the table has been sorted

Tags: php, tablesorter

I'm doing a system where the user is able to sort the information in the table before submit the form. User can click on the each table column heading to sort the information. The problem is when user sort the table, the data cant be submitted. Im using post method to submit the form.

this the js script to sort the table:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
   { 
      $("#tbl").tablesorter(); 
   } 
);
```

script for the table:

```
<form method="post">
<table width="80%" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse; border: #ccc;" class="tablesorter" id="tbl">
<thead>
  <tr height="25">
  <th width="4%">NO</th>
  <th width="10%">PRODUCT CODE</th>
  <th width="30%">PRODUCT NAME</th>
  <td bgcolor="#FFCC99" style="font-weight:bold; text-align:center" width="4%">APPROVE</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
while($prow = mysql_fetch_assoc($getprods)){
    $pcode = $prow['prod_id'];
    $getdetails = ibase_query("select * from STOCK where STOCKCODE = '".$pcode."' and INACTIVED = 'F'");
    while($srow = ibase_fetch_assoc($getdetails)){
        $itemcode = $srow['STOCKCODE'];
        $itemname = $srow['STOCKNAME'];

        $ctr++;
?>
<tr class="row">
  <td><center><?php echo $ctr.'.'; ?></center></td>
  <td width="149">&nbsp;<?php echo $itemcode; ?>&nbsp;</td>
  <input type="hidden" name="code<?php echo $ctr; ?>" id="code<?php echo $ctr; ?>" value="<?php echo $itemcode; ?>">
  <td width="373">&nbsp;
    <a href="po_itemdetails.php?itemcode=<?php echo $itemcode; ?>" class="nyroModal" target="_blank"><?php echo $itemname; ?></a>
  </td>
  <td>
    <center>
      <input type="hidden" name="prod_id<?php echo $ctr; ?>" id="prod_id<?php echo $ctr; ?>" value="<?php echo $prow['id']; ?>">
      <input type="checkbox" name="appr<?php echo $ctr; ?>" id="appr<?php echo $ctr; ?>" value="<?php echo $itemcode; ?>">
    </center>
  </td>
</tr>
<?php
    }
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
<input type="text" name="total" value="<?php echo $ctr; ?>">
</form>
```

script to retrieve the data that has been submitted:

```
<?php
for($i = 1; $i <= $_POST['total']; $i++)
{
    echo $_POST["code$i"];
}
?>
```

if user didnt click on the table column heading to sort the data, the information can be submitted without any error. If user click on the table column heading, no data will be submitted.

Comment: `<tbody>
while($prow = mysql_fetch_assoc($getprods)){
$ctr++;
<tr class="row">
` looks like you're missing some `<?PHP ... ?>` tags here

Comment: are you saying you want the form disabled if user clicks heading or that your code has a problem and you want data correctly sent if heading has been clicked.

Comment: @JanDvorak yes, bcos i didnt copy the script into here. hehe

Comment: Then what's that, if not your script? Even if your code is compressed for us (good thing), you need to verify it still demonstrates the problem (common error) and that it doesn't develop a set of syntax errors of its own (more common than it should be).

Comment: @Class I want the data correctly sent if the heading has been clicked. Because if u notice, for each input, it has its own id with a number at the back. Normally, i just get the total row, n loop the data. But, once it has been sorted, i cant get the correct data, as the number has been randomized.

Comment: @JanDvorak the script has been edited. Sorry for the mistake.